# Sync liferay and AD's distribution groups

Tags: active-directory, synchronization, content-management-system, liferay

Our Active Directory already have a Distirbution Groups which contains users divided on departments.

How can I sync this distribution groups to "**User groups**" and than send emails to them? It will be conveniently, bcs Distribution groups everytime are updated and correct.